# Why is a suffix automatically appended to the git worktree internal directory name?

Tags: git, git-worktree

When creating a new worktree by `git worktree add foo <revision>`, in the main worktree `.git/worktrees/foo/` is also created. I've encountered a situation several times, where it creates `.git/worktrees/foo1/` instead. I think `1` is appended because there are some naming conflicts. I'd like to know why this happens and how to replicate the case. Thanks.

FYI, multiple threads may work in the same main worktree to create different worktrees, and git version 2.31.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean "**in** the main worktree", are you nesting worktrees?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I mean the default worktree of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git worktree add` code synthesizes the worktree ID (internal name) in [`add_worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b80121027d1247a0754b3cc46897fee75c050b44/builtin/worktree.c#L239-L240), using this loop:

```
        if (safe_create_leading_directories_const(sb_repo.buf))
                die_errno(_("could not create leading directories of '%s'"),
                          sb_repo.buf);

        while (mkdir(sb_repo.buf, 0777)) {
                counter++;
                if ((errno != EEXIST) || !counter /* overflow */)
                        die_errno(_("could not create directory of '%s'"),
                                  sb_repo.buf);
                strbuf_setlen(&sb_repo, len);
                strbuf_addf(&sb_repo, "%d", counter);
        }
        name = strrchr(sb_repo.buf, '/') + 1;
```

The initial `sb_repo.buf` consists of a "sanitized" name derived from the path, where in your case the path is the name `foo` added to the Git directory and the worktrees subdirectory (`$GIT_DIR/worktrees/foo`).  The `len` here is the point where the numeric suffix part goes in.  So, if the initial `mkdir` call fails with `EEXIST`, the `foo` part of the `sb_repo.buf` strbuf is replaced with `foo1`, `foo2`, and so on, until the `mkdir` call either succeeds (returns 0) or fails with something other than `EEXIST`.

> [Sometimes Git] creates `.git/worktrees/foo1/` instead. I think 1 is appended because there are some naming conflicts.

This would happen if there's already a `.git/worktrees/foo`, so that the `mkdir` call returned an error with `EEXIST` as the error number.  That in turn would happen if there were a worktree whose path ended with `foo`, or something that sanitized to `foo`.]

[Note that you can also see random errors with Git repositories when they are stored in a cloud-synced folder (ICloud, Dropbox, etc). The cloud-syncing software reaches into the repository and damages it in its attempt to synchronize it.  That's probably not the case here though.]

(It's a bit curious as to why you *care* where the worktree-specific files live inside `$GIT_DIR`.  I'm not sure why Git goes to all this effort to make a base name, rather than just generating randomized IDs using `mkdtemp` or an equivalent: had Git done that, people would not be tempted to poke around inside `.git/worktrees` as much.  To use worktree-specific refs like `HEAD` and bisect revision names, use `git rev-parse` or `git update-ref`, which knows how to do this on its own.  There *is*, I think, a bit of a problem with temporary index files: the index file needs to be per-worktree, and it would be nice to have `git rev-parse --git-internal-worktree-path` or some such for constructing such names.)

Comment: Thanks, torek! It's indeed the multiple different worktree paths with the same ending `/foo`, like `/a/b/foo` and `/a/c/foo`, that cause increasing numeric suffixes. I care it because previously the command `git sparse-checkout` was not introduced and we wanted to read and write `.git/worktrees/foo/info/sparse-checkout`.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. A lot of the time when you're using bleeding-edge stuff like the ongoing sparse checkout work, you hit these kinds of edge cases. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> To use worktree-specific refs like HEAD and bisect revision names, use `git rev-parse` or `git update-ref`, which knows how to do this on its own.

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b50a608ba20348cb3dfc16a696816d51780e3f0f), instead of manually creating `refs/` hierarchy on disk upon a creation of a secondary worktree, which is only usable via the files' backend, use the refs API to populate it.

See [commit 8f4c00d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f4c00de954f809e83daf8b1425de82561f3721e), [commit b8a846b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8a846b2e03610e6f550d364c75e514532ef7adf), [commit 84f0ea9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84f0ea956fbd3a3c9989a2d44da27881c0a5f546), [commit 2eb1d0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2eb1d0c45271faf149a13b61bb74af52abd7b3aa), [commit c358d16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c358d165f2a4b3176b527e18c207105f6821335e), [commit 2e573d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e573d61ffe3d1e7ea94673757fb69477c1499bc) (08 Jan 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
See [commit 5bf20d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bf20d6c77500f3ad95451421725ee2122ef5610) (08 Jan 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc8ce99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc8ce995a2ad203ffb5ef335682b64da955e645a), 26 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f4c00de954f809e83daf8b1425de82561f3721e): create refdb via ref backend
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When creating a worktree we create the worktree's ref database manually by first writing a "HEAD" file so that the directory is recognized as a Git repository by other commands, and then running `git-update-ref(1)` or `git-symbolic-ref(1)` to write the actual value.
> But while this is fine for the files backend, this logic simply assumes too much about how the ref backend works and will leave behind an invalid ref database once any other ref backend lands.
>
> Refactor the code to instead use `refs_init_db()` to initialize the ref database so that `git-worktree(1)` itself does not need to know about how to initialize it.
> This will allow future ref backends to customize how the per-worktree ref database is set up.
> Furthermore, as we now already have a worktree ref store around, we can also avoid spawning external commands to write the HEAD reference and instead use the refs API to do so.
>
> Note that we do not have an equivalent to passing the `--quiet` flag to `git-symbolic-ref(1)` as we did before.
> This flag does not have an effect anyway though, as `git-symbolic-ref(1)` only honors it when reading a symref, but never when writing one.

That means it will not always be `.git/worktrees/foo1`, if the backend is no longer a file-based one.